# Java programming, look for the connection of a key in the array

Tags: java, arrays, search

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package w01s03p;

import static java.sql.Types.NULL;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author WIN8
 */
public class task5 {

    private static int hitLevel;
    private static int attackLevel;
    private static int defLevel;
    private static int LEVEL;
    private static int numberOfData;
    private static String[] arrName;
    private static int dataCounter;
    private static int dataOfCounter;
    private static int inputChoice;
    private static double temp;

    public static void main(String[] _args) {

        int numberOfData = 3;
        int i, temp = 0;
        int inputChoice;
//declaration
        String[] arrName;
        double[] arrHP;
        double[] arrAP;
        double[] arrDP;
        double[] hitLevel;
        double[] attackLevel;
        double[] defLevel;
        double[] LEVEL;

        //instantiation
        arrName = new String[numberOfData];
        arrHP = new double[numberOfData];
        arrAP = new double[numberOfData];
        arrDP = new double[numberOfData];
        hitLevel = new double[numberOfData];
        attackLevel = new double[numberOfData];
        defLevel = new double[numberOfData];
        LEVEL = new double[numberOfData];

        do {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            System.out.println("Monsville Tournament");
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            System.out.println("1.List Monster");
            System.out.println("2.Best By Hits Point");
            System.out.println("3.Best By Attack Point");
            System.out.println("4.Best By Defense Attack");
            System.out.println("5.Search Profile");
            System.out.println("6.Registration Monster");
            System.out.println("0.Quit");
            inputChoice = Keyin.inInt(" Your Choice: ");
            switch (inputChoice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("List Monster : ");
                    if (arrName == null) {
                        System.out.println("Input Monster");
                    } else {
                        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Monster Name " + arrName[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Daftar Best HP!");
                    if(arrHP != null){
                    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        if (arrHP[i] < arrHP[i + 1]) {
                            temp = (int) arrHP[i + 1];
                            arrHP[i + 1] = arrHP[i];
                            arrHP[i] = temp;
                        }
                        System.out.println("HP (" + arrHP[i] + ")    :" + arrName[i]);
                    }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Daftar Best AP!");
                    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        if (arrAP[i] < arrAP[i + 1]) {
                            temp = (int) arrAP[i + 1];
                            arrAP[i + 1] = arrAP[i];
                            arrAP[i] = temp;
                        }
                        System.out.println("AP (" + arrAP[i] + ")    :" + arrName[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Daftar Best DP!");
                    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        if (arrDP[i] < arrDP[i + 1]) {
                            temp = (int) arrDP[i + 1];
                            arrDP[i + 1] = arrDP[i];
                            arrDP[i] = temp;
                        }
                        System.out.println("DP (" + arrDP[i] + ")    :" + arrName[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Search Profile Monster");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        System.out.print("Monster Name: ");
                        arrName[i] = scanner.next();
                        System.out.print("hit point: ");
                        arrHP[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("attack point: ");
                        arrAP[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("defense point: ");
                        arrDP[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid selection");
                    break;
            }
        } while (inputChoice != 0);

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (arrHP[i] >= 100) {
                hitLevel[i] = 3;
            } else if ((arrHP[i] >= 50) && (arrHP[i] < 100)) {
                hitLevel[i] = 2;
            } else if (arrHP[i] < 50) {
                hitLevel[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (arrAP[i] >= 20) {
                attackLevel[i] = 3;
            } else if ((arrAP[i] >= 10) && (arrAP[i] < 20)) {
                attackLevel[i] = 2;
            } else if (arrAP[i] < 10) {
                attackLevel[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (arrDP[i] >= 15) {
                defLevel[i] = 3;
            } else if ((arrDP[i] >= 5) && (arrAP[i] < 15)) {
                defLevel[i] = 2;
            } else if (arrDP[i] < 5) {
                defLevel[i] = 1;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            LEVEL[i] = +hitLevel[i] + attackLevel[i] + defLevel[i];
        }

        System.out.println("---------monster profile ---------\"");

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("name         : \"" + arrName[i] + "\"");
            System.out.println("hit point    :" + arrHP[i]);
            System.out.println("attack point :" + arrAP[i]);
            System.out.println("defense point:" + arrDP[i]);
            System.out.println("level        :" + LEVEL[i] + "(" + arrHP[i] + "/" + arrAP[i] + "/" + arrDP[i] + ")");
        }

    }

}
```

I wish to find the monster by it's name in a search query but I don't know how to search for the monster's information by it's name. The monster's information is separated in many arrays. If `inputChoice` is 5, then it should prompt the user to find a monster's profile.

Thankss

Comment: Maybe maybe if your code would be less confusing than your question; we could help. But you see: your code itself is **hard** to read (names like arrName, arrHP, ... just dont help) ... that few people will have interested in translating your strange question into code.

Comment: One hint: do not create 5 different arrays that carry different properties of a "player" (like one for player names, one for player points, ..). Instead: create a class that represents one **Player** and give that class all the attributes that a player should have. And then create **one** array to hold player objects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One hint: do not create 5 different arrays that carry different properties of a "player" (like one for player names, one for player points, ..). Instead: create a class that represents one Player and give that class all the attributes that a player should have. And then create one array to hold player objects! – **GhostCat**

Perfect response from GhostCat.

But if you're not following his advice, you'd have to do it like this:

1. Get input from the console, i.e: the name of the monster;
2. Search for the name in the monster array.
3. If the name matches the input, save the index of that monster
4. Obtain all info from that monster using that index number.

The code would look similar to:

```
String searchQuery = scanner.next();
int indexFound = -1;
for(int x = 0; x < arrName.length; x++) {
    if(arrName[x] != null && (arrName[x].toLowerCase().equals(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) || arrName[x].toLowerCase().contains(searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
        indexFound = x;
        break;
    }
}

if(indexFound != -1) {
    System.out.println("Monster Found by the name of " + searchQuery)
    System.out.println("name         : \"" + arrName[indexFound] + "\"");
    System.out.println("hit point    :" + arrHP[indexFound]);
    System.out.println("attack point :" + arrAP[indexFound]);
    System.out.println("defense point:" + arrDP[indexFound]);
    System.out.println("level        :" + LEVEL[indexFound] + "(" + arrHP[indexFound] + "/" + arrAP[indexFound] + "/" + arrDP[indexFound] + ")");
} else {
    System.out.println("Monster not found");
}
```

Place that piece of code under your `case 5:`.

Comment: thanks for the help, it will be a lesson for me to make the code more simple in the future, the code you provided is correct, but the user must provide a new input name will appear monsters full detail with the monster's name itu.padahal user should only need to enter part of the name monster and will show results that contain some of the words.

 Your Choice:  5
Search Profile Monster
fe
Monster Found by the name of fe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at w01s03p.task5.main(task5.java:126)

Comment: @FensiusAritonang I'm sorry, the last if-else statement is checking on `index` instead of `indexFound`. Editting my answer.